# peekBottom method in stack by singly linked list

Tags: java

i have done the peekTop which is the regualar peek function? what will be the difference for the peek bottom?

how do i get the last element?

```
public E PeekTop() {
    if (isEmpty()) 
    System.out.print("stack is empty ");
    return top.getElement();
```

Comment: how do you get the next element?  repeat until you get to the end...

Comment: I assume "peek bottom" would peek the other end of the linked list.  I would ask whomever is giving you the assignment what they meant.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [jtahlborn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/552759/jtahlborn), if your stack is implemented via a singly linked list, you'll need to traverse the entire linked list in order to retrieve the item at the bottom of the stack - i.e.:

```
public E PeekBottom() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println("Stack is empty - no bottom");
        return null;
    }
    E stackItem = top;
    while (stackItem.hasNext())
        stackItem = stackItem.next();
    return stackItem.getElement();
}
```

Comment: will this be right ? if i do it like this ?
public E PeekBottom() { 
   if (isEmpty()) System.out.print("stack is empty "); 
   while (top.getNext()!= null) {
    E temp=top.getElement(); 
   return top.getElement();}
    
  }
@ jtahlborn

Comment: Not quite. At the very least you'll need to move the `return` statement outside of the `while` loop. Beyond that I believe you'll need to remove the `temp` variable - just assign `top` to its element - i.e. `top = top.getElement()` instead of `E temp=top.getElement()`.